# How does middleware work in NextJS if you cannot export it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

As I am trying to implement a system where users will not be able to access admin routes unless they are authenticated, to do this you need a middleware. But the problem is I am using nginx on my website, and you cannot use middleware on this, as it says:

```
error Middleware cannot be used with "output: export". See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html
```

I am so confused on how this all works. How will you be able to use a middleware? Are there ways to not give users access to routes eg: `[website]/admin/items/list` unless they are authenticated?

Comment: The `output: export` tries to make a bunch of static assets out of your application. All server-side processing is [not available in this mode](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports#unsupported-features). Your application will support server-side features only if hosted on a [server-side nextjs runtime behind nginx](https://gist.github.com/jjsquady/5399d6e1b23f501083a9c262d806e248).

Comment: Does this mean middleware still runs as long as its running nginx? but of course it will not be served with the static files?

Comment: nginx doesn't usually handle nodejs requests internally, rather it forwards them to a running nodejs service that can even be installed on a separate machine, available locally to the nginx.